# how to install tensorflow serving offline

Tags: tensorflow, serving

My server is in my company network which disconnected to the internet. I can only downloads the required files in other office computer and upload them.

I git clone 

`git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/serving
cd serving 
cd tensorflow 
./configure cd ..`

`Configuration is ok as the default advices.
 But when I want to bazel the repository.`

[root@centos7 /data/mig_predictor/pre_installation/serving]# bazel build -c opt ... --package_path /data/mig_predictor/pre_installation ......... 
```

`ERROR: error loading package 'serving/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '//tensorflow/core:platform/default/build_config_root.bzl': BUILD file not found on package path. ERROR: error loading package 'serving/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '//tensorflow/core:platform/default/build_config_root.bzl': BUILD file not found on package path. INFO: Elapsed time: 0.481s`

How can I pointed the local repository for the predownloaded packages?
Thank you!

Comment: I found some configuration in the file "WORKSPACE" .

Comment: But I have no idea to verified the file and use the proper command to compile the codes,Thank you guys!